# Android M Developer Preview - adb devices not working

Tags: android, adb, fastboot, android-6.0-marshmallow

I flashed the Android M developer preview to my Nexus 5 tonight and now I can't get ADB to recognize the device. I have developer options enabled and when I reboot to the bootloader the command "fastboot devices" lists my device. I feel like I may be missing something simple.

Any ideas what could be wrong?

Edit: I have also tried both MTP and PTP USB configs, restarting the device, and unplugging and plugging the cable back in.

Comment: have you enabled usb debugging ?

Comment: I can't believe it. Obviously it's been a long time since I've had to do this. Thank you. I think I need some sleep.

Comment: it happens sometime :p